# How to update data to an object created from a custom view class ,so that it can be drawn on custom view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

My application requires to post data to a custom view and redraw the view according to sent data from MainActivity.
Here are sample code.
Custom view->

```
public class custom_view extends View {
 private simple_line line;
 public custom_view(Context context) {
     super(context);
     line=new simple_line(0);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     line.draw_line(canvas);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight());
 }

 private class simple_line{
     private float x_val;
     private Paint mpaint;

     public simple_line(float val){
         x_val=val;
         mpaint=new Paint();
         mpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
         mpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         mpaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
     }

     public float getX_val() {
         return x_val;
     }

     public void setX_val(float x_val) {
         this.x_val = x_val;
         invalidate();
     }

     public void draw_line(Canvas canvas){
         Path mpath=new Path();
         mpath.moveTo(getWidth()/2+x_val,0);
         mpath.lineTo(getWidth()/2+x_val,getHeight());
         mpath.close();
         canvas.drawPath(mpath,mpaint);
     }
 }

 public void update_xval(float val){
     line.setX_val(val);
 }
}
```

Here is Main activity->

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private Button button;
private custom_view myview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
myview=(custom_view)findViewById(R.id.myview);
myview=new custom_view(this);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myview.update_xval(100);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I am unable to update x_val  when button is pressed.Where am I going wrong.What needs to be done to update x_val?

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue in `draw_line(Canvas canvas)` function. you are not calling this function in `custom_view`. you need to `invalidate()` after `draw_line(Canvas canvas)`called.

Comment: I had forgotten to add line.draw_line(canvas) in onDraw{ } method.After adding it. still not working.I have also added invalidate() method after draw_line(Canvas canvas) is called.Still not working.